# Flutter Contacts plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Flutter contacts plugin, it works great but I noticed that the phone number that gets displayed isn't clickable... meaning you cant press on it and make a call with that number like if you google a place of business and can call the number by pressing on it. Is there an easy way to do this or would we have to use url-launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use url-launcher plugin or use Flutter's plugin SelectableText. With SelectableText widget user will be able to select the text, in this case, phone number, and then Android should give the option to call that number. You can find documentation about SelectableText widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way as far as i know is to handle a call is with the package:
[Pub Package](https://pub.dev/packages/intent)

Also you can use the plugin mentioned by Antonio Valentic, and then you can create a function to pass the phone number to the intent something like this:

```
Intent()
    ..setAction(Action.ACTION_CALL)
    ..setData(Uri(scheme: 'tel', path: 'YOUR NUMBER'))
    ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
```